# Change font size on web when rescale browser

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am trying change text size on my Flutter web page. With googling, I found this solution:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      builder: (context, child) {
        final MediaQueryData data = MediaQuery.of(context);
        print('----> ${data.textScaleFactor}');
        return MediaQuery(
          data: data.copyWith(
              textScaleFactor:
                  data.textScaleFactor > 2.0 ? 2.0 : data.textScaleFactor),
          child: child!,
        );
      },
```

However, font size is not changed when I change a chrome width size and `print('----> ${data.textScaleFactor}');` always returns 1.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Use a container with variable size according to screen and use a FittedBox to wrap the child Text.

```
Container(
          height: height * 0.15,
          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: width * 0.9),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            child: Text(
              'Text you want to display',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Calibri',
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Thanks bro, I know a few ways but I want to know why my code not work. Thanks again.